# Using MySQL WKB

Tags: mysql, mysql-spatial

I am using MySQL version 8.0.29 and I have an issue with WKB string, I will simplify query here

```sql
SELECT ST_GeomFromWKB(X'0103000020E61000000100000005000000834B0400800125C0AE8645BE2BCE484089E20C00805011C0AE8645BE2BCE48407DB4FBFF7F5011C0333D29DFA8544B40834B0400800125C0711727DFA8544B40834B0400800125C0AE8645BE2BCE4840')
```

but this query runs fine

```sql
SELECT ST_GeomFromWKB(X'0103000000010000000500000000000000800125C07CAF45BE2BCE4840000000000088FD3F7CAF45BE2BCE4840000000000088FD3F7D7F0B0026DB4D4000000000800125C07D7F0B0026DB4D4000000000800125C07CAF45BE2BCE4840')
```

return an error : **[22001][3037] Data truncation: Invalid GIS data provided to function st_polygonfromwkb.**

but I can validate with online resources that WKB is valid and polygon is valid as well
https://tools-utils.com/wkb-to-wkt/

I have looked at MySQL documentation but was not able to find any answer, maybe someone had a similar issue?

Original Geometry that throws error:

```
POLYGON((-10.502929688 49.610709938,-4.328613282 49.610709938,-4.328613281 54.661403556,-10.502929688 54.661403555,-10.502929688 49.610709938))
```

Comment: Please edit your question, it is now hard to understand which geometry gives an error with MySQL.

Comment: @user30184 Done

Comment: Does ST_PolyFromWKB work?

Comment: You have written "but this query runs fine", then a query, then "return an error :". Does that query run fine or return an error?

Comment: Those are different queries, WKB is not same

Comment: @MrR no ST_PolyFromWKB is not working, same error